# Use different route template for controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

Is it possible to change the Routing controller name in MVC? In MVC 5 I would have done this:

```
[RoutePrefix("MySpecialSauce")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [Route("GetBy/{id}")]
    public MyObject GetBy(int id)
    {
        return something(id);
    }
}
```

Now all I can find is to use the default name of your controller:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet("GetBy/{id}")]
    public MyObject GetBy(int id)
    {
        return something(id);
    }
}
```

I want to use a different name for my route than actual controller name. How do you do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the same in Core

```
[Route("MySpecialSauce")]
public class ProductsController : Controller {

    [HttpGet("GetBy/{id:int}")]//Matches GET MySpecialSauce/GetBy/5
    public MyObject GetBy(int id) {
        return something(id);
    }
}
```

`[controller]` is a token replacement to help with route template. it is not mandatory.

Source [Token replacement in route templates ([controller], [action], [area])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area)

> For convenience, attribute routes support token replacement by
>   enclosing a token in square-braces (`[`, `]`). The tokens `[action]`,
>   `[area]`, and `[controller]` will be replaced with the values of the
>   action name, area name, and controller name from the action where the
>   route is defined.